# How to add a sorting column in Reports

Tags: civireport, reports, 4.6, sort-order

I have a report that I would like sorted by County but that field doesn't appear as a sortable column, although it does appear on the report. This field is in fact 'State/Province' but is renamed via word replacement to 'County' (I am in the UK).  There are other fields that appear as sortable that are surprising because their usefulness is very dubious (like Notes) but County doesn't appear.  Is there some way to make this field appear?

Comment: Could you elaborate on which report you are running with perhaps a screen shot?

Comment: It's based on the template of 'Constituent Report (Summary)' - I can't post a copy as it has confidential info.  But you've prompted an idea to instead base the report on ''Constituent Report (Detail)' which does allow sorting on State/Province.  I'll let you know as this is probably the answer

Comment: Basing the report on the 'Detail' template solved the problem but introduced a new one (isn't that usually the case!) because now the formatting is poor. One of the fields is a note, which was handled OK before but is now all squashed up. But odd that in the detailed template I can sort and group by state/province but not in the summary template.